# Getting a handle on date conversion in R

Tags: r

I created a column of dates by hand.
Need to convert entire column Date to xx/xx/xxxx (01/dd/2012)
I know how to use substrings to extract month day year from a standard data class like 01JAN12

```
DateM=substr(Date,START,FINISH)
DateM
Now put it together as xx/xx/xx
```

Here is my code:

```
Date=c("January 23,2012","January 24,2012","January 
        25,2012","January 26,2012","January 27,2012")

# WANT: 23JAN12  24JAN12  25JAN12  26JAN12  27JAN12
Date3=format(Date,"%B %d %Y") 
# Error in format.default(Date, "%B %d %Y") : invalid 'trim' 
  argument but I still get the dates ok when I print out

#WANT: 01/23/2012 01/24/2012 01/25/2012 01/26/2012 01/27/2012 from 
       Date3
Date4=format(Date3,"%B  %d  %Y")  
invalid 'trim' argument

# WANT: 2012-01-23 2012-01-24 2012-01-25 2012-01-26 2012-01-27
Date5=format(Date3,"%Y %B  %d")  
invalid 'trim' argument
```

I want to use the basic functions of R as opposed to `lubridate`. 
Can someone direct me how to finish this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `as.Date` and not `format`

```
as.Date(Date, "%B %d, %Y")
#[1] "2012-01-23" "2012-01-24" "2012-01-25" "2012-01-26" "2012-01-27"
```

`as.Date` is used to convert dates from different character representation to `"Date"` class.

Once you have data in the `"Date"` class, we can then use `format` to represent them in the way we want.

```
format(as.Date(Date, "%B %d, %Y"), "%m/%d/%Y")
#[1] "01/23/2012" "01/24/2012" "01/25/2012" "01/26/2012" "01/27/2012"
```

Comment: What does %B stand for ? %m stands for month. I have seen it done both  ways -%B and %m. What is the rule for use here? MM

Comment: @MaryA.Marion `%B` is for complete month name based on the language in your locale. So if you have "English" as your language `%B` is for "January", "February" etc whereas `%m` stands for month in numbers. So 1 for January, 2 for February and so on. More explanation and description can be read at `?strptime`.